# Access SQL Dual Like Join

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

```
SELECT [Table1].[Field1], [Table 1].[Field2], Count([Table2].[ID]) AS [CountOfID]
FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN [Table1] ON ([Table2].[Field1] Like "*" & 
[Table1].[Field1] & "*") AND ([Table2].[Field2] Like "*" & 
[Table1].[Field2] & "*")
GROUP BY [Table1].[Field1], [Table1].[Field2];
```

Above is what I am trying to do. I have two table and need to use two joins (I believe) to create the two groupings that I need. The fields typically contain a list such a "Red/Green/Blue" or "Strawberry/Banana/Grape" and [Table2].[FieldX] will always contain the unique list of [Table1].[FieldX].

Results should be as follows example.

```
[Field1]   [Field2]    [Count]
Strawberry Red         10
Strawberry Green       2
Banana     Yellow      15
Grape      Green       7
Grape      Red         20
```

The issue is the counts are never right which I believe is to do with the join, help as to how to correct this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's because you are getting multiplication on your JOINs (table1 counts * table2 counts, for each match).

Comment: Not quite sure why or how to fix in that case? I thought it was where its in field1 AND field2 then count?

Comment: As you figured out, a subquery to insure a set of unique values is one way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benefit in using a join with wildcards which will force a serial read on both tables anyway. I do not know if this will work, but I would try to write this query as follows:

```
SELECT [Table1].[Field1], [Table 1].[Field2], Count([Table2].[ID]) AS [CountOfID]
FROM [Table2], [Table1] 
WHERE ([Table2].[Field1] Like "*" & [Table1].[Field1] & "*") 
  AND ([Table2].[Field2] Like "*" & [Table1].[Field2] & "*")
GROUP BY [Table1].[Field1], [Table1].[Field2];
```

Comment: Hey, its a similar issue, its not returning all options for [Table1].[Field2]

Comment: Ok, I did switch to a WHERE statement but the issue was within my [TableX]. Had to use a subquery. Instead of FROM [Table2] its now returning all unique values within the table, clearly it wasnt what I thought it was.

Comment: This is the same logical query.  It may make a difference to performance (because Access is not highly optimized), but it will not produce different results.